# HTML Form Confirm Submission bug

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

When I tested out my blacklist confirm dialog, I clicked the ok button which normally submits the form, but in my case, it was not submitting but instead kept going in a loop of which I clicked it, nothing happened and the dialog was still showing. The only way I got it to submit the form so far is by clicking the ok button once, then clicking the cancel button which is not normal. I want it to submit when I pressed the ok button only once. Below is the js code I used for the dialog:

```js
    function confirm_blacklist() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to blacklist {{ user.name }}?")) {
            console.log("submitting");
            $("#blacklist-form").submit();
            console.log("submitted");
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function confirm_unBlacklist() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to unBlacklist from {{ user.name }}?")) {
            console.log("submitting");
            $("#unBlacklist-form").submit();
            console.log("submitted");
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Both of these are the same, it's just different wording for the confirm message and different id for the two forms.

Below is the HTML section that uses these functions:

```html
    <div id="ext-option-menu" class="ext-opt-align">
        {% if user.blacklisted %}
        <form id="unBlacklist-form" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm_unBlacklist()" action="{{ url_for('admin.adminAccountsUserManagement', user=user.name) }}">
            {{ ext_options.reason }} {{ ext_options.unblacklist }}
        </form>
        {% else %}
        <form id="blacklist-form" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm_blacklist()" action="{{ url_for('admin.adminAccountsUserManagement', user=user.name) }}">
            {{ ext_options.reason }} {{ ext_options.blacklist }}
        </form>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Is there a way to fix this bug?

Comment: Instead of `$("#blacklist-form").submit();` use `return true` same for other as well.

Comment: @Swati Thank you, that worked, but could I receive an explanation on why `$("#blacklist-form").submit();` did not work as I used this same thing but with a different id on a different form and that form worked perfectly fine. Could you do it as an answer please with including the solution to my problem?

Comment: I have added answer please check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this behaviour because you have written `onsubmit="return confirm_unBlacklist()"` so when you click on submit button and if user click on `ok` then you are again triggering `$("#unBlacklist-form").submit();` so again same function gets called and its goes into infinite loop . Instead you can use `return true` so this will submit your form .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function confirm_blacklist() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to blacklist {{ user.name }}?")) {
    console.log("submitting");
    return true;
    console.log("submitted");
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function confirm_unBlacklist() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to unBlacklist from {{ user.name }}?")) {
    console.log("submitting");
    return true;
    console.log("submitted");
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ext-option-menu" class="ext-opt-align">

  <form id="unBlacklist-form" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm_unBlacklist()" action="{{ url_for('admin.adminAccountsUserManagement', user=user.name) }}">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

  <form id="blacklist-form" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm_blacklist()" action="{{ url_for('admin.adminAccountsUserManagement', user=user.name) }}">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

</div>
```